# I don't know why my cassandra has such a large hints table?

Tags: apache-spark, solr, cassandra, datastax

My cluster has 2 datacenters. The first datacenter has 1 node with spark and solr enabled, the other datacenter has 5 nodes with spark enabled. After a while all the nodes have a couple of 100GB hints table. But my node status is all available and normal. It doesn't show the nodes are down but the hints table just keeps on increasing. The consequence is that the after a while all the disc space will be used and the nodes die and the system crashes. I don't know why this happens?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which nodes/data center have the growing hints tables but my guess would be that the 1 node data center does not have sufficient processing capacity to keep up with the writes replicated from the 5 nodes data center. I would say that this is particularly the case when using Spark - Spark writes can easily overwhelm a cluster unless you're using the cassandra.output parameters to control write speed.

Another factor here is the consistency level you are using - a LOCAL_* consistency level will only require writes to be written to the local DC for the operation to be considered a success (and hints will be stored for replication to the other DC).

Cheers
Ben

Comment: Thanks for your great reply. What consistency level should I use? without having to keep hints and at cheapest write cost.

Comment: I don't think I can give you a general answer to that - the appropriate consistency level will depend on your requirements. Also, the consistency level doesn't control how many copies Cassandra wants to write eventually, just how many have to be written for the operation to be reported to the client as successful. Replication strategy controls who many copies Cassandra want to write in total. Are you using networktopologystrategy as your replication strategy? That would at least help you control how many copies of the data are written to each DC.

Comment: Thanks. I use networktopologystrategy as my replication. How can I avoid the hints to be stored for replication to the other DC? They have no use for me and they just keep growing and growing in size. Maybe I just don't get what they are good for since they didn't appear in the past.

Comment: The hints are the records of writes that have been made in one DC that are not yet replicated to the other DC (or even nodes within a DC). I think your options to avoid them are:  (1) write with ALL or QUOROM (not LOCAL_*) consistency - this will slow down your writes but will ensure writes go into both DCs before the op completes  (2) Don't replicate the data to the second DC (by setting the replication factor to 0 for the second DC in the keyspace definition)  (3) Increase the capacity of the second DC so it can keep up with the writes  (4) Slow down your writes so the second DC can keep up.

Comment: One other thing to add - I just discovered that cassandra 3.x has a new nodetool command - _disablehintsfordc_ which would do what you want (although I guess with the need to run repair to properly synch data). https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsDisablehintsfordc.html